# QProcess:exitCode() does not appear to return %errorlevel%

Tags: qt, qprocess, errorlevel

I am trying to catch specific error codes from a windows command line application run as a QProcess.

I had an error today where the application fails: 
When run on the command line: echo %errorleve% returns 14001 (ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX) which is the correct error.

In my Qt application though when I call exitCode() on the QProcess that calls this application I get 0 as the return value.

Is there a way to get the correct errorlevel of this process?  I expect I'm missing something simple.

ex:

```
proc_->start(bridge_config_.exePath(), args);
if (proc_->state() == QProcess::NotRunning){
    handleProcessFailedToStart(proc_->exitCode());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

QProcess::start doesn't block until the process starts or even terminates. Thus when you call exitCode() right away, it won't be valid as the process didn't even start yet.
You can connect to the finished() and error()  signals (the non-blocking alternative, recommended in a UI application) to get the exitcode, or call waitForStarted() and/or waitForFinished() (blocks, useful in secondary non-UI threads or in CLI programs) and then exitCode().

Comment: finished() and error() signals are never fired in this case. (I assume because the process never actually begins due to the sxs issue).  This is why I added the detection of state change.

Comment: I added waitFroStarted(-1) and there is no change to the exitCode().

Comment: I have the same problem as the original question:  `waitForFinished()` blocks, but the exit code is always zero, even though the command DID NOT return zero (Qt4.8, Win7/64, MSVS2008)

Comment: charley: Does waitForFinished() return true? What's returned by errorString(), exitStatus(), error() and state()?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, `QProcess::waitForFinished()` *always* returns `true` (I wrap the return value with an `ASSERT()`)  My "solution" is to parse the command-line-output and "determine" the "real" success/fail for the command execution. (Not ideal, but, it works...)